# How to make a hanging icicle brush or graphic style in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, style, brush

I purchased a set of graphic styles for Illustrator. The set contains a style that applies a hanging icicle brush to any object, so that icicles appear to be hanging from any horizontal line of an object.

I've decided I'd like to make my own icicle brush or style, rather than using a prefabbed one. However, I cannot figure out out to get an effect only to apply to the horizontal parts of an object, as the prefabbed one does.

I've tried making a pattern brush, but that inverts the icicles so that the "bottom" horizontal pattern points upward and into the object, rather than hanging from it. The pattern brush also creates the pattern on the vertical sides of objects, with the icicles pointing into the object. This is not my desired behavior.

How do I create a brush or style that creates hanging icicles from horizontal lines of a path, not on the vertical lines, and still hangs from the bottom of the object rather than pointing upward and into it?

Example below... I want the sort of stylized icicles I created for the 2nd example (not pink obviously, color changed to stand out against white for the example.. but I want the icicles to hang rather than point to the center of the object.

[image: Icicles]

Comment: Kind of need to see a sample.

Comment: Are you referring to these? https://stevencrawley.wordpress.com/2014/10/16/icicle-layered-brush-set/ if so.. did you read this? http://stevencrawley.wordpress.com/2014/10/12/how-do-you-make-icicle-brushes-just-face-down/ Google found this immediately.

Comment: Scott, thank you! I guess it must be down to the exact search terms used... but anyway, that has provided my solution, and I am extremely grateful. I figured it had to be simpler than my overanalytical mind was trying to make it. Thanks a million!

Comment: I simply searched for "Illustrator Icicle Brushes". The first result answered your question.

Comment: Ahh, I searched for all sorts of terms about making brushes that point downward, etc...

Answer (score 1):

As **Stephen Crawley** explains regarding his icicle brushes, it's simply a matter of using the proper **Scatter Brush** settings. You need the brush to be relative to the *page*, not the *path*.

**[You can read Mr. Crawley's blog post by clicking here:](http://stevencrawley.wordpress.com/2014/10/12/how-do-you-make-icicle-brushes-just-face-down/)**

Comment: Hi and welcome to GD.SE **:P** In general we frown upon one line answers that contain just a link. Could you summarize what is under the link. Lets face it sites go down all the time and this post might become obsolete. Because your new ill let it slide this time :)

Comment: I'll do better @Joojaa :)